# Software for converting HEX file to human-readable text

Tags: data-recovery, database, hex-editor, ultraedit

I need some suggestions for software that can convert corrupted database file opened as hexadecimal.

I used UltraEdit to open the database file as text. I want the text *circled* in red to be converted to a text file, because I can't copy it from the current text editing software.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's already in plain text, there's nothing 'hex' here. Just open the file in Notepad, or if it's notably larger than the ~16KB in this screenshot grab Notepad++, and use regular ctrl-C from there.

Comment: All I see in Notepad++ is NUL NUL NUL..

http://i.imgur.com/Q1fhlPT.png  The file is 50 MB.

Comment: Ctrl-F "WebkitDatabaseInfoTable", shift-Home, Del.

Comment: Yeah, it is there. But why Notepad++ shows that NUL NUL part but UltraEdit doesn't ? In UltraEdit it shows as a text.

Comment: The 'NUL' squares are just bytes containing 0, which cannot be part of a 'regular' text file, therefore UltraEdit decides to render it with the hex editor instead. Notepad and derivatives only have text mode, so they render it inline instead. Doesn't change that at some point in the file there is plain text content.